# Does Stackdriver convert different time units in logs to milliseconds?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

I have log data in the rough format:

```
textPayload: "latency=1.539325257s method=GET"
textPayload: "latency=355.376208ms method=GET" 
textPayload: "latency=704.816053ms method=GET"
textPayload: "latency=751.597856ms method=GET"
textPayload: "latency=1.845525343s method=GET"
```

And I have created a Distribution Metric in Stackdriver using the regex: `latency=([0-9.]+)` which extracts the latency (and is converted to a double by stackdriver)

When I graph this data it appears to show the values "1539.32" and "1845.52" on my charts, suggesting those `s` values are being converted to `ms`.

That is what I would want, but I can't find anywhere that says Stackdriver *actually* reads the suffix of the unit (it definitely isn't part of my regex) and converts the time to a standard unit. Is this is the *actual* behavior of Stackdriver?

Comment: As of now there is no such direct feature in 'Stackdriver' which actually reads the suffix of the unit  and converts that time to a standard unit(or any custom unit). That's being said,I would recommend you to create one such feature using the '[issue-tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#search_for_or_create_bugs_and_feature_requests_by_product)' link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stackdriver definitely isn't converting between time units for you, it is just extracting the `double` value and treating it as whatever unit you specify in your custom metric, in my case `ms`. We ended up changing our logging code to always output in `ms` and never "pretty print" the value into something like `3.293s` and `2m51s` which is the default when dealing with a golang `time.Duration`.

A graph is worth a thousand words, see if you can spot where we deployed that code change.

[image: the true latency is revealed]

Answer (score 0):

it might be better to filter eg. for `httpRequest.latency`, see https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#HttpRequest.

> **latency** - A duration in seconds with up to nine fractional digits, terminated by 's'. Example: "3.5s".

see [agent metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_agent#agent).

Comment: These are actually logs from golang apps running inside GKE containers, so there aren't any Stackdriver Agents in this case